# why am i getting: "cannot seek vector iterator after end"

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, runtime-error

So I am trying to solve [josephus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)  problem using c++

First input is number of people and second is position for killing next person

I am getting run-time error as: "cannot seek vector iterator after end"

code:

```
// josephus.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int people = 0, pos = 0;

    cin >> people >> pos;

    vector<int> vp;

    for (int i = 1; i <= people; ++i)
    {
        vp.push_back(i);
    }

    int index = 0;

    while (vp.size() != 1)
    {

        index += pos - 1;

        if (index >= vp.size())
        {
            index -= vp.size();
        }

        vp.erase(vp.begin() + index);
        
    }

    cout << vp[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Funny thing is for input data 10 3 (people = 10, pos = 3) there is no error. It gives correct answer 4.

But for input 94 31 (people = 94, pos = 31) It gives me run-time error.
I think problem occurs at erase function.

I have tried everything I can. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider what happens when `pos` is 31, but `vp` only has 7 element in it.

Comment: Debugger shows erase being called with index out of range. Oh hey, that sounds a lot like "cannot seek vector iterator after end" Interesting.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you! You pointed me in the right direction. I used modulo operator instead of subtraction and now it works! Thank you everyone who commented and answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior because according to the requirements for sequence containers the argument of the member function `erase` shall be a valid **dereferenceable** iterator. However due to this statement

```
index += pos - 1;
```

the value of `index` can be greater than or equal to the value of the expression `2 * ( current size of the vector)`.

In this case in the next if statement

```
    if (index >= vp.size())
    {
        index -= vp.size();
    }
```

`index` will get a value that is greater than or equal to the value of `vp.size()`.

As a result this call

```
vp.erase(vp.begin() + index);
```

will not use a valid **dereferenceable** iterator.

Comment: Yes, should have used modulo operator instead of subtraction for circular traversal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As 1201ProgramAlarm mentions is the comments, `index` can be greater than `vp.size()`, which means that when you try to erase `vp.begin() + index`, it will fail because there is no element after `vp.end() - 1`. `vp.begin()` and `vp.end()` are iterators, so when you try to *seek* an iterator after end (`vp.end()`), it fails tells you exactly that.